# how to get params from templateDetails.xml in joomla 3.1

Tags: php, xml, joomla, parameters

I want to get params form templateDetail.xml to use this in my template. But every time i do

```
$this->params->get('Title', 'test');
```

i only get test, it seems he cant find the param title.

this is my templateDetail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 2.5//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/2.5/template-install.dtd">
<extension version="3.0" type="template" client="site">
  <name>Basic Joomla 3.0 Template</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <creationDate>10/04/2012</creationDate>
  <author>Gazar</author>
  <authorEmail>info@gazar.nl</authorEmail>
  <copyright>Copyright (C) 2013 Gazar</copyright>
  <description>My first JOOMLA template!</description>
  <files>
    <filename>index.php</filename>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
    <folder>fonts</folder>
  </files>
  <positions>
        <position>debug</position>
        <position>hoofdmenu</position>
        <position>slider</position>
        <position>position-0</position>
        <position>position-1</position>
        <position>position-2</position>
        <position>position-3</position>
        <position>position-4</position>
        <position>position-5</position>
        <position>position-6</position>
        <position>position-7</position>
        <position>position-8</position>
        <position>position-9</position>
        <position>position-10</position>
        <position>position-11</position>
        <position>position-12</position>
        <position>position-13</position>
        <position>position-14</position>
  </positions>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <field name="Title" type="text" default="Gazar" label="Title" description="Vul hier de titel van uw site in!" />    
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Any one who knows how to accomplish this?

PS: Do i have to tell JOOMLA where the params are set? Or do JOOMLA know that he needs to look in the templateDetails.xml?

Comment: try this $this->params->get('Title');

Comment: i get NULL back when i do that

Comment: i think its bcoz of fieldset tag missing check that

Comment: already tryed, but stil not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You missed fieldset tag in xml

```
<fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">
                    <field name="title" type="text" default="Gazar" label="Title" description="Vul hier de titel van uw site in!" />  
        </fieldset>
            </fields>
```

and to get params try

```
echo $this->params->get('title');
```

Comment: check your default template xml like beez_20 it has the same thing. try using title instead of Title

Comment: i solved it, the problem was that the template was active when i added the params, so he didn't recognize. But when i changed template once and edited the template from: templates / options. it recognized and its working now :D